# Pycharm thinks I'm using python 3.5< but I'm using 3.7

Tags: ide, pycharm

I'm getting this error on PyCharm, the code runs fine but for some reasons the IDE thinks I'm using the wrong version of python. Is there a way to fix this?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This means that the inspections check for code compatibility with Python 3.5.

To modify this go to `File -> Settings -> Editor -> Inspections -> Python -> Code compatibility inspection` When you click on that latter line, on the bottom right of the window is the list on compatibility checks you can have. You can tick or untick the Python versions you want.